# Is it possible to use Sass & BEM in Joomla system?

Tags: sass, joomla, bem

I am new to Joomla and after doing some research I haven't found a solution whether it is possible to make use of the combination of Sass & BEM (Block Element Modifier) in a Joomla environment?

Answer (score 0):

SASS precompiles to CSS.  Methodologies like BEM, SMACSS, etc are essentially used for naming conventions so they really have no technical bearing on the final CSS output.

The short answer is yes, you can use SASS and BEM to create/modify the Joomla CSS.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm well clued up with BEM and SMACSS and the rest.

Comment: My concern is how to implement a module or plug in into joomla that supports sass and BEM preferably BEM Constructor which is a sass library created by Daniel Guillan https://github.com/danielguillan/bem-constructor